# Calculate series sum(turning bounds)?

Tags: sequences-and-series

$\sum_{n+1}^0 -k(3^k) $
assuming (n+1)<0

As far as I understand I should use the formula for $\sum_{0}^{N-1} k(a^k) $ but what should I do the get to this formula?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$a+b = b+a$. It doesn't matter which order you add  $$\sum_{k=n+1}^{k=0} -k(3^k) = \sum_{k=0}^{k=n+1} -k(3^k) $$

Next let $u = -k$,
when $k=0, u = 0$
when $k=n+1, u = -(n+1)$

$$ \sum_{k=0}^{k=n+1} -k(3^k) =  \sum_{u=0}^{u=-(n+1)} u(3^{-u}) = \sum_{u=0}^{u=-(n+1)} u(1/3)^u   $$

Comment: but (n+1)<0 so how can you that

Comment: one sec.. let me grab a paper

Comment: Since (n+1)<0, we have -(n+1) > 0. your formula should work with a=1/3 and N = -n. @arn please see if above is what you're looking for